# Enumerate open ports in same process

Tags: windows, winapi, sockets, tcp, port

Is there any way in Windows for a process to enumerate all the open ports/sockets it is using?  I'm trying to track down some high port usage in my app, but my app uses very few, so it must be some other DLL getting loaded into the process.

Comment: I suggest WinDbg and a breakpoint on `socket()` (as well as `WSASocket()`) in `wsock32.dll`.  When you hit the breakpoint, check the call tree.

Comment: That will only tell you which modules are creating sockets, but not which IP/Port they are using.  You would have to hook `bind()`, `accept()` and `WSAAccept()` instead to get that information.

Comment: @Remy: AFAICT, the point of his question is to figure out what his app does that causes ports to be opened (by a library).  Which can be done by getting a port list before and after each library call and seeing when the list grows.... or much more easily by setting breakpoints.  Focus on the problem being solved, not the approach suggested in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows' own command-line `netstat` utility, as well as the SysInternals' [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) app, can display the name of the process that owns each open port.

If you want to enumerate this information programmably, you will have to enumerate Windows' port routing tables manually and map them to your process.  On XP, you can use [`AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365804.aspx) and [`AllocateAndGetUdpExTableFromStack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365807.aspx). On Vista and later, you can use [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) and [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930.aspx) instead.  Both sets of functions can return the Process ID of each open IP/Port, which you can then compare to the result of [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180.aspx).

Comment: But he doesn't know WHICH ports are being used by his process, which is the point of his question.  The API functions I mentioned can be used to determine that information.

Comment: Thanks Remy -- that's what I need (programmatic access so I can log the ports for running at customer sites)